# Why do many job changes seem to occur in February?

Tags: career-development, new-job, job-change

I've noticed something weird over the last two years, mostly because I've been paying more attention to my colleagues' movements on LinkedIn. Many seem to take on a new job in the month of February, and many others seem to have work anniversaries in February (meaning they started their current job in the month of February).

What is special about this month? Is that when managers go on some aggressive hiring binge? Or is it because people have finished their performance review from the previous year and decided to move on?

Comment: Part of it could be a subtle manifestation of [SAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasonal_affective_disorder), in addition to the other reasons put forward.

Comment: If you don't even mention your country and industry, this is unanswerable. Your observation could be confirmation bias.

Answer (score 10):

Generally hiring is slow from late October until the new year. Often people are on vacation and often budgets are tight, as the end of the fiscal year is coming up.

All that breaks free in January and it takes until about February to actually go through the process of advertising for a position, evaluating and hiring the candidates, and waiting for them to work out their notice period.

Comment: Does this imply that the best time to look for a new job is in January, or the previous few months (November-December)?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 if you are looking for a government job in the US, this is a definite yes. Fiscal years often kick off in October or November, which is when funding for new positions become available. Sometimes there is a lag betsween when funding becomes available and a position gets posted, pushing the posting to December or January.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to [HLGEM's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/22914/168), often people have annual or quarterly bonuses that they need to be at the company to collect. So once that constraint releases you will see a spike in job movement.

Answer (score 2):

The need for hiring depends upon a lot of external and internal factors.

Performance Review and Increments is one cause.

Also, organisations run in a financial cycle from  January - December. They close their books by December and plan for the coming year. New budgets are allocated for human resources, wherein based on the company strategy a lot of hiring is done.

It could also happen because of the nature of Industry. for example if you are looking for a job as a teacher in India, there is a fair chance that you will get maximum opportunities in May-June & November -December, because of the summer and winter semester cycles.